# Visual Studio C++ - Check the reason of link a specific library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, linker

vs report a error such as:

1. can not find xxx.lib
   How do I check out why vs need to link xxx.lib? Is there a trace log? My project have not use boost.regex, but vs report a error says can not find regex.lib. So I want to find out which part of code refer to regex
2. LNK error: LIBCMT.lib: xxx was already defined in LIBCMTD.lib
   How do I check why vs also link yyy.lib even this is a debug build? I have 2 projects, they link to same libs, all libs and project itself was /MTd. But one of them will report above error, I think it shouldn't link LIBCMT.lib because it is a release version lib, and another project is OK so the lib file was build correctly

VS can show the link trace?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Let's start with how the linker actually knows what to link with. Basically there are 2 categories:

- Libraries specified in the project settings in the linker options as additional inputs
- Libraries added in code with precompiler directive `#pragma comment` (generally the same thing as above but people have different tastes)

Otherwise you just get information about missing symbols but not the actual library they are from. What you can do to help is under visual studio linker options set `Show Progress` to `For Libraries Searched` (or just `/VERBOSE:LIB` linker flag), that will actually show you what dependencies are added after each lib is loaded, this also helps with point 2) to see which library loads which run-time.

2) Already mentioned in 1) that you can make the linker show library load progress, otherwise if a dynamic C run-time is used in the external library you are linking against you could use [`Dependency Walker`](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to examine the dependencies of the library and find if the C run-time dll that is needed is debug or release by 'd' suffix in the dll name. If the library is already linked with static run-time then I guess only the linker errors will warn you. But I think that most serious libraries are correctly packed and structured so that you will be able to tell which files contain the debug version and which the release. If the library has only release version, well than that's another story. But i mean still, you can reconfigure the `Debug` configuration of your project to actually link against the release run-time to satisfy the external library, of course this prevents some debugging features, debug heap, etc.

Comment: Linker---General---Show Progress is exactly what I need, that help me find the lib which incorrectly link to LIBCMT.lib

Comment: So, what other issues are uncovered, or what should i add for you to accept the answer?

Comment: In the log of /VERBOSE, regex.lib is listed in "Unused libraries:". What is it mean? If it is unused, why vs needs link to it? I have not refer to regex anywhere, I had searched it in solution, no occur.

Comment: Well, the second post actually states that as i explained in 1) - you can add library dependencies with the `#pragma comment` if your  code includes that header then you will get the library dependency. Did you try defining the macro `BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB` above all includes?

Comment: I have not use #pragma comment. After open BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB, regex is no longer show in log. It seems boost auto link will add every thing whatever it finally will be used or not. The regex should be introduced by asio, however, regex is unnecessary because I have not call asio's relative function.

Comment: Well, as @the_mandrill explained, you don't need to put the `#pragma comment` directive in the code yourself, it is enough that you include a boost header which indirectly or directly includes another boost header that has this pragma, an that is how it ends up telling the linker to use the regexp library. So now you are able to link?

Answer (score 4):

For the missing boost regex library problem, I think the cause is due to boost's default autolink behaviour. If you include one of the headers of some of the boost libraries (not all of them, but regex is one of them), then these will cause Visual Studio to automatically link against the library. It uses a special pragma of the form:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "regex")
```

This has the effect of automatically adding a flag to the linker command. However, it's only picked up during compilation and so you won't see it in the project properties.  In the case of boost, the solution to this is quite simple - find `boost/config/user.hpp` and uncomment the line

```
#define BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB
```

This will turn off the autolink behaviour for all libraries. Alternatively you can use `#define BOOST_REGEX_NO_LIB` to change this just for the regex library.

To solve the second problem, you need to find out which library is linking against the release build. Try selecting all projects in the solution and open Properties -> C++ -> Code Generation. You will probably find that the Runtime Library setting will be blank (because the option is different for some of the libraries. Force it to the correct threaded/single-threaded Debug option and rebuild.